# Execute Checkbox action once checked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, checkbox

The objective is to execute href from input checkbox once checked

checkbox Input

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{{$todo -> id}}" name="{{$todo -> ToDoName}}">
```

js

```
/* The todo list plugin */


 $(".todo-list").todolist({
    onCheck: function (ele) {
      window.console.log("The element has been checked");
      return ele;
    },
    onUncheck: function (ele) {
      window.console.log("The element has been unchecked");
      return ele;
    }
  });
```

Comment: input checkbox have no class still

Answer (score 0):

Create a new html file, and copy paste the following codes :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="checkbox" class="todo-list" value="True" name="{{$todo -> ToDoName}}">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            (function(){
                $(".todo-list").change(function(data){
                    var value = this.checked;
                    if (value == true){
                        console.log("The element has been checked");
                    } else {
                        console.log("The element has been unchecked");
                    }
                });
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Explaination :

> - You did not give a name to your checkbox class
> - The change is triggered every time checkbox is checked and unchecked
> - To get the checked and unchecked value, you need to get this.checked (this refers to the checkbox element, since we're modifying this element's change event)